# SSIS Control Flow Diagram is now empty

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I had a working SSIS package last week. I came back into the office this morning, opened up the package and tried to open up one of the Data Flow tasks. Double clicking did nothing. I closed the project and reopened it and received an error message that there was a "Catastrophic Error" and that the layout could not be displayed. The Control Flow diagram now only showed my two Sequence Containers.

I made a copy of the dtsx file then went into it manually with a text editor and found that some of the XML was duplicated. I removed the "extra" copy and reopened my package. The empty Sequence Containers are now gone, but I still can't see any of my components. I looked at the Package Explorer and everything is still there, but it's just not displaying in the designer. I was even able to run the package successfully.

Is there any way to rebuild the package so that I can see everything in the designer? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why BIDS has decided the layout is junk but you can get around the issue by removing the layout and forcing BIDS to regenerate that information. The graphical layout stuff is a cool idea for conceptualizing how a package is organized but the implementation of storing that information, serialized XML inside XML, is pants.

There are various articles available about how to remove the XML, but this is a more recent example of how to use do this. http://joshrobi.blogspot.com/2012/04/editing-existing-ssis-package-via-ezapi.html

As always, ensure you have a good copy of the package before editing the XML directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a backup of your package - try and restore that to another location first to make sure that is not corrupted.

How are you accessing the package, are you connecting remotely to a server hosting SSIS, or are you using tools located locally on the server?

I've encountered issues when trying to access packages across networks before.

Also, as a word of warning it's not good practice to edit package contents before carrying out further diagnosis!

Comment: The latest backup of the package is missing a lot of work, so I'd like to restore this one to working order if at all possible. The package is local. A backup of the package was made before I did any manual editing.